# Nuxt2.js with i18n how to choose the preferred behavior of prefix_and_default strategy?

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

I'm using `@nuxtjs/i18n": "^7.3.1"`

When `prefix_and_default`  strategy is used and I visit `http://localhost:3000/en`
the `'/en'` prefix gets removed because it's the default language,
but what if I want to keep the prefix if the user visited `http://localhost:3000/en` ?
as mentioned in the [docs](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/strategies#prefix_and_default)

> This strategy combines both previous strategies behaviours, meaning
> that you will get URLs with prefixes for every language, but URLs for
> the default language will also have a non-prefixed version (though ***the
> prefixed version will be preferred*** when detectBrowserLanguage is
> enabled).

how would I **prefer the prefixed version**?

even more: can I choose which pages the prefixed version would be preferred and which ones to remove the prefix from?

here is my configuration of `i18n` in `nuxt.config.js`

```
i18n: {
    locales: [
      {code: "en", iso: "en", file: "en.js", dir: "ltr"},
      {code: "ar", iso: "ar", file: "ar.js", dir: "rtl"},
      {code: "fr", iso: "fr", file: "fr.js", dir: "ltr"}
    ],
    lazy: true,
    baseUrl: "https://mywebsite.com",
    defaultLocale: "en",
    strategy: "prefix_and_default",
    langDir: "~/lang/",
    detectBrowserLanguage: {
      useCookie: true,
      cookieKey: "i18n_redirected",
      redirectOn: "root" // recommended
    },
    vueI18n: {
      fallbackLocale: {
        en: ["fr", "ar"],
        fr: ["en", "ar"],
        ar: ["en", "fr"]
      },
    }
  },
```